# How to add a bootstrap carousel in a React Project/

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, carousel, react-bootstrap, styling

I have used bootstrap for my styling in my react project.But when I tried add carousel there was an error here is my code

```
function Home({user}){
    return (<>
    <h1 class="greeting">Hey {user.name}! Welcome to JetSet</h1>

    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade frame" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ82m6eL2lonNbE-6-MGRl2RN-VUAB8Epse45lpCCdH-k68O8TbEiG1E1V3biNXlHplT5M&usqp=CAU" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
    </>)
}
export default Home;
```

I inserted the bootstrap in my react component However im getting this error (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.img: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ImgHTMLAttributes, HTMLImageElement>.....this is becuz JSX element 'img' has no corresponding closing tag and when i add the closing tag the carousel dosent work.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Bootstrap 4, then it requires the Query, Popper.js, and bootstrap 4 JavaScript plugins.

Jquery is another js library, using a library(jQuery) inside a library(react) is not an ideal solution. better you should use react-bootstrap for react project [click here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/carousel/#rb-docs-content)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CDN for that if you don't want to add another module. Just add it in the '/public' where your index is.

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

And you can use it by looking into the documentation.